# PHP Readfile() not working for me - maybe header problem?

Tags: php, download, readfile

I checked similar posts and here's the problem: a portion of my codes :

```
if($_GET['dl']) {

$file=$_GET['dl'];
$file="../../rep/".$file;

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");

readfile($file);
exit;}
```

This code runs when user submit form and redirects on current PHP file. The result opens in browser rather than download. I checked a lot of other headers or modifications with no clue.

So I made a separated PHP file : download.php and paste the above code **exactly** on it. then redirect user to this new file And Problem solved! (File downloads without any problem)

**So my question is what's the problem exactly?**

Comment: Does the existing code (before you paste into a separate file) output anything to the browser before you send these headers? If it does, they won't be sent.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, please go and do that first of all! Then PHP will likely tell you, that it could not send any headers at this point, because you created output before already.

Comment: And that is not the biggest problem of that code, btw. It currently allows for easy _path traversal_, meaning it could be used to download _any_ file from within your webspace, even outside of the `rep` folder.

Comment: @droopsnoot You mean functions like echo or print? No at all. These codes are in the top of the file.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your hint but this file protected by htaccess (nobody run it except root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks from comments, the reason founded!
I had started the PHP tag <?php from **second line** in the file like this:

- ...
- php tag start here <?php

Perhaps first line considered as an output.removed first line and now download starts properly ;)

Comment: That's what I meant, not just `echo` or `print` - even white-space in the text file before the opening PHP tag gets sent to the browser.